# Java process memory usage keeps increasing and java native memory tracking shows "Internal" consumes lots of memory

Tags: java, memory, internal

Java 1.8.0_131 + Windows Server 2012 R2.

'-Xmx=9000m'. But Windows Task Manager shows the java process uses more than 14 GB memory.

NMT shows "Internal" consumes more than 4.5 GB memory. Why does this occur? I understand it is not Java functionality to define spaces for the native memory. But is there any method to limit the 'Internal' memory?

Total: reserved=15782485KB, committed=14653869KB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=9216000KB, **committed=9216000KB**)
                            (mmap: reserved=9216000KB, committed=9216000KB)

- Class (reserved=1277553KB, committed=260193KB)
                          (classes #37738)
                          (malloc=11889KB #64612) 
                          (mmap: reserved=1265664KB, committed=248304KB)
- Thread (reserved=80528KB, committed=80528KB)
                          (thread #79)
                          (stack: reserved=79872KB, committed=79872KB)
                          (malloc=244KB #398) 
                          (arena=412KB #157)
- Code (reserved=166388KB, committed=55208KB)
                          (malloc=10356KB #10526) 
                          (mmap: reserved=156032KB, committed=44852KB)
- GC (reserved=340353KB, committed=340277KB)
                          (malloc=3521KB #1861) 
                          (mmap: reserved=336832KB, committed=336756KB)
- Compiler (reserved=290KB, committed=290KB)
                          (malloc=160KB #947) 
                          (arena=130KB #2)
- Internal (reserved=4513559KB, **committed=4513559KB**)
                          (malloc=4513495KB #7980353) 
                          (mmap: reserved=64KB, committed=64KB)
- Symbol (reserved=52759KB, committed=52759KB)
                          (malloc=48180KB #563951) 
                          (arena=4579KB #1)
- Native Memory Tracking (reserved=134867KB, committed=134867KB)
                          (malloc=108KB #1634) 
                          (tracking overhead=134759KB)
- Arena Chunk (reserved=190KB, committed=190KB)
                          (malloc=190KB)

Comment: May I ask what the hell you are doing? I feel bad for the RAM. It must be so filled up. Strange that it didn't puke yet ^^. But really: What are you doing to cause that?

Comment: Actually the process crashes with the OOME because of failed to allocate more memory.This is a Java process of an enterprise system. It is loading lots of objects into the Java process. That's the reason why it uses '-Xmx=9000m'. But we found the Java process consumes about 14.5 GB RAM, which alsmost consumes most of the server RAM and JVM failed to allocate more memory to the Java process. And the NMT output shows the Internal Category consumes more than 4.5 GB memory.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it was confirmed the issue was caused by DynaTrace Agent.

After removing DynaTrace Agent the issue does not occur any more. And the issue also does not occur after applying the DynaTrace update.

Comment: Hi Brent,
Could you please update the answer, how did you find that DynaTrace was causing the problem. We've the same problem in prod system.